# Capistrano / ubuntu

Tags: capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I'm attempting to set up a staging server in my rails 4 app. When i run 'cap staging deploy', the command aborts with the following error:

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 7

bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

The 'cap abort' follows:

```
Could not find font-awesome-sass-4.0.2 in any of the sources
```

Any ideas for how to find what this means? Font awesome sass 4.0.2 is definitely in my gemfile and installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause of this but I had the same issue with paper_trail, updating to a later version and then redeploying did the trick for me.